# How to handle SQLiteException

Tags: android, android-sqlite

What should I do if an `SQLiteException` is thrown? I know that I can catch it. But what's next? Should I log it and throw it again and let the app crash?

Docs say that even `getWritableDatabase()` can throw an `SQLiteException`:

> **public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase ()**
>
> Errors such as bad
>   permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future
>   attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.
>
> **Throws**
>       SQLiteException   if the database cannot be opened for writing

This is not under my control. So, what should be done with an exception that I cannot recover from or fix?

Comment: Firing exception means there is some data missing issue in your code

Comment: Do you actually have a problem involving SQLiteException? Or is there some other reason you are asking?

Comment: I'd simply display a Toast and some colored label or bullet (red in case of a failure) on the UI. Maybe I'd write a log file, too. But I'd continue executing my app, without crashing it.

Comment: @VVB Yes. That is my responsibility. My question is about the exception being thrown outside my control.

Comment: @Karakuri No I do not have a SQLiteException problem right now. I am asking what the expected response of this exception should be. The premise is that the exception is thrown outside my code. Docs say that if there is low-storage space, getWritableDatabase might throw this exception. How should the app respond?

Comment: @DerGolem I would also prefer this. Is there any forum post or article or blog post that discusses on this issue? I checked the source code in /packages of android framework. Some apps do follow your approach of documenting and ignoring the exception. Others insist on crashing explicitly by throwing SQLiteException. And some don't even have a catch(SQLiteException) block.

Comment: What I do is simply surrounding my rawQuery and execSQL code by a try... catch... finally. - I open my db connection, try doing my CRUD, eventually catch the SQLException if any to act consequently and finally close the db connection.